# asp.net with connection to sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis

i am new in using asp.net language and i try to edit code asp.net which is already connected to a database on iis server

the problem that i faced is:

i can retrieve all table that already exist on that database but when i add new table i cannot retrieve it on asp.net "not found"

the same problem when i add new column all already exist column , i can retrieve them except the columns that i added them

but when i edit record , the record updated on asp.net so the problem when i create any thing or alter name of a column

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe your last sentence answers this, but are you sure you're connecting in .NET to the same database you're looking and adding fields:tables to ?
Anyway some code may be of help, the problem is probably not where you think...

Comment: Can you post some more information like connection string and/or webconfig file?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of data access technology are you using? ADO.NET Entity Framework (one with `.edmx` file) or ADO.NET (one with `.xsd`)?

If you are using one of these you need to refresh or add tables in these diagrams too. Otherwise please get your code here so that picture gets clearer.